# How to customize the positional embedding?

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I am using the Transformer model from Hugging face for machine translation. However, my input data has relational information as shown below:

[image]

I want to craft a graph like the like the following:

```
 ________
 |       |
 |      \|/
He ended his meeting on Tuesday night.
/|\ |         |          /|\
 |  |         |           | 
 |__|         |___________|
```

Essentially each `token` in the sentence is a node and there could be an `edge` embedded between the tokens.

In a normal transformer, the tokens are processed into token embeddings, also there is an encoding of each position which resulted into positional embeddings.

How could I do something similar with the edge information?

Theoretically I could take the edge type and the positional encoding of a node and output an embedding. The embeddings of all the edges can be added to the positional embeddings for the corresponding nodes.

Ideally, I would like to implement this with the hugging face transformer.

I am struggling to understand how could I update the positional embedding here:

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/longformer/modeling_longformer.py#L453

```
        self.position_embeddings = nn.Embedding(
            config.max_position_embeddings, config.hidden_size, padding_idx=self.padding_idx
        )
```

Comment: The code you posted is different from the URL you provided. Can you please have a look? I am not that familiar with AMR graphs, but couldn't you simply add another embedding layer that contains a vector for each edge label? Each token that has an incoming edge adds the corresponding edge vector to the token vector.

Comment: @cronoik, thanks for your response. The question is not really about AMR graph. Fundamentally I want to know how could I embed relational (edge) information in a transformer. My intuition is I have to modify positional embedding somehow and incorporate the edge information.

Comment: That depends on what you want and where you want to do something with it. There are so many possibilities. Let's stick to what I described above. In this case, you want to handle it on the word embedding layer  (i.e. token embedding+position embedding+incoming edge embedding) and you, therefore, need to add another embedding layer in line 456 and use its output in 478 (I am referencing the lines in the github code you shared).

Comment: All ways I currently can imagine do not require any changes to the position embedding layer. At first, you need to decide how you want to incorporate the edge information on an abstract level before you can go into implementation details.

Comment: @cronoik  your response is very vague. Do you want to provide a proper answer? I started a bounty.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that. Without an understanding of AMR, I can not give you a proper answer.

Comment: It's unclear whether you know this from your post, so I'd like to point out that most AMR datasets do not have token alignments: AMR graphs are paired with sentences, but there is no alignment between nodes in that graph and tokens. It is possible to generate alignments, but they will not be perfect. Cf. https://amrlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rbw_aligner/, https://github.com/goodmami/penman/issues/19, https://www.isi.edu/~damghani/papers/amr_eng_align.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your question is generally about how to use linguistic representations to enrich word representations in Transformer language models. This is an open research question with no clear answer. One option given by [Prange et al. (2022)](https://aclanthology.org/2022.naacl-main.325/) is to define a function which returns a subgraph of the whole-sentence graph given a particular token, and to process the token's subgraph so that it is represented in a fixed-length vector which can then be readily combined with the token's representation for use in the rest of the Transformer LM. Their related work section reviews other approaches and is worth a look.